# ¿Cómo obtener una variable de Session en una vista con arquitectura MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net

Tengo un controlador, con un método **Index** y lo que requiero es que a partir de la *session* en mi **vista** se oculten o muestren datos, es decir, requiero que si el rol es 10, entonces la **vista** se oculten los Url.Action y se muestren otros a partir de la sesion del usuario.

**Controlador:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var clientes = db.Clientes.ToList();
        var IdUsuario = Convert.ToInt32(Session["IdUsuario"]);
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["IdRol"]) != 2 || Convert.ToInt32(Session["IdRol"]) != 7)
        {
            clientes = (from uc in db.Usuarios_Clientes
                        join cc in db.Clientes on uc.IdCliente equals cc.IdCliente
                        join us in db.Usuarios on uc.IdUsuario equals us.IdUsuario
                        where uc.IdUsuario == IdUsuario
                        select cc).ToList();
        }


        // clientes = clientes.Where(x => x.IdUsuario == IdUsuario).ToList();
        return View(clientes.OrderBy(x => x.RazonSocial));
    }
```

**Vista:**

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RazonSocial)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RFC)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <a title="Crear" href="@Url.Abs(Url.Action("Crear", "Trabajadores", new { IdCliente = item.IdCliente }))"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></a>
                            <a title="Eliminar" href="@Url.Abs(Url.Action("Eliminar", "Trabajadores", new { IdCliente = item.IdCliente }))"><i class="fa fa-user-times"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente la solución está en un **`@if()`** en la Vista pero de esta manera:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RazonSocial)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RFC)
    </td>

    <td>
    @if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["IdRol"]) != 10)
    {
        <a title="Crear" href="@Url.Abs(Url.Action("Crear", "Trabajadores",
            new { IdCliente = item.IdCliente }))"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar" href="@Url.Abs(Url.Action("Eliminar", "Trabajadores",
         new { IdCliente = item.IdCliente }))"><i class="fa fa-user-times"></i></a>
    }
    else { 
       // Aquí la otra alternativa.
    }
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Sigueindo la **conversión de tipos** que tu mismo utilizas, hay que convertir `Session["IdRol"]` a `int` para poder compararlo. 
Esto: `Session["IdUsuario"] != 10` **no funciona** (lanzará una excepción).

Comment: Asi es, valide con el if() sin la conversión y mando excepción, muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un @if dentro de tu vista donde compares el valor de tu session sea diferente de 10 simplemente no se muestra

ejemplo:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RazonSocial)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RFC)
                        </td>

                        <td>
@if (Session["IdUsuario"]!=10)
            {
                            <a title="Crear" href="@Url.Abs(Url.Action("Crear", "Trabajadores", new { IdCliente = item.IdCliente }))"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></a>
                            <a title="Eliminar" href="@Url.Abs(Url.Action("Eliminar", "Trabajadores", new { IdCliente = item.IdCliente }))"><i class="fa fa-user-times"></i></a>
}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

Comment: gracias, si valide con el if() pero como traigo el ID en un entero, se debe de convertir, ya logre que sucediera, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.